# Interface-based polymorphic collection

Tags: c++, c++11, collections, polymorphism

Here is a small C++11 utility collection to store any object that satisfies a given interface. Only the basic concepts are provided, I did not try to create a full collection:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

template <typename Interface, template <typename> class Adapter>
class poly_collection
{
public:
    using iterator = boost::indirect_iterator<typename std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>>::iterator>;

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    auto push(Args&&... args)
        -> void
    {
        auto ptr = new Adapter<T>{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        entities.emplace_back(ptr);
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto push(T&& other)
        -> void
    {
        auto ptr = new Adapter<T>{ std::forward<T>(other) };
        entities.emplace_back(ptr);
    }

    auto begin()
        -> iterator
    {
        return { std::begin(entities) };
    }

    auto end()
        -> iterator
    {
        return { std::end(entities) };
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> entities;
};
```

Here is an example of use. Imagine you have an abstract class named `Shape`. For the sake of simplicity, it will only have one abstract method, `draw`:

```
struct Shape
{
    virtual void draw() const = 0;

    virtual ~Shape() {};
};
```

Now, you have some nice classes, `Rectangle` and `Circle`, that you didn't write but that satisfy the `Shape` interface:

```
struct Circle
{
    Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {}

    void draw() const
    {
        std::cout << "Circle\n";
    }
};

struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int height, int width) {}

    void draw() const
    {
        std::cout << "Rectangle\n";
    }
};
```

You would like to store `Rectangle` and `Circle` instances in a colleciton as if they inherited from a common base class. With our solution, you only have to write a new class: `ShapeAdapter`, and then feed it to the `poly_collection`:

```
template<typename T>
struct ShapeAdapter:
    Shape
{
    template<typename... Args>
    ShapeAdapter(Args&&... args):
        data(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    virtual void draw() const override
    {
        data.draw();
    }

    T data;
};

int main()
{
    poly_collection<Shape, ShapeAdapter> shapes;

    shapes.push<Circle>(1, 2, 3);
    shapes.push<Rectangle>(4, 5, 6, 7);

    Circle c = { 8, 9, 10 };
    shapes.push(c);

    for (auto&& shape: shapes)
    {
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

So, what do you think of the idea? Would that be an interesting utility? Is there any way I could improve such a collection appart from adding some functions to mimick the standard library's collections ones?

Comment: Is this a try in modeling what Sean Parent talked about here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil

Comment: @Nobody No idea. Talks always bore me, so I never watch them.

Comment: @Nobody It has to do with the slides "value semantics and concept-based polymorphism" though. Maybe those are the slides used in the talk.

Comment: Parts of it are these slides (I believe).

Comment: Why do you need the adapter? Seems like you could just put objects that implement the interface directly into storage. This feels like `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: @LokiAstari As it is often the case with your comments - which are generally relevant comments -, I am going to ask for some example (a good to an online compiler would be great). I don't see how I could get a proper polymorphic behaviour without the adapter.

Comment: OK. Took me a second. But I had initially assumed that `Circle/Rectangle` inherited from `Shape`. So you have a container that can hold objects that implement a particular interface without actually inheriting from the interface. Not sure I like the idea. But hey ducks are ducks.

Comment: @LokiAstari From what I have read, it is called "concept-based polymorphism". I used such a thing once when I didn't want to write wrappers for loads of mathematical objects in a ray tracer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual with your code, I can only come up with very minor nitpicks.

With both `push` functions, there is a small chance of a memory leak. After the construction of a new `Adapter<T>` using:

```
auto ptr = new Adapter<T>{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
```

If `entities.emplace_back(ptr);` fails (say if relocation is required, the vector needs to expand, and this fails), then `ptr` will leak. Instead of doing it this way, I'd suggest using `make_unique` and moving the `unique_ptr` into `entities` using `push_back` instead:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto push(Args&&... args)
    -> void
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Adapter<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    entities.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by LokiAstari I would also use a `boost::ptr_*` container which does the pointer wrapping for you.

Writing your own container(wrapper) puts the burden of forwarding some members onto you. For example your `poly_collection` does not define the usual `pointer`, `reference`, `value_type` (and some more) member types to identify as "real" container. Your usecase does not depend on this (and you might not intend to use them in any other way) but why should you worry about this, when you can do it another way.

Looking at your `poly_collection` it strikes me as odd that you have to store the adapter's type in it. Looking more closely this is only used in the push functions (which btw. should be called `push_back` or rather `emplace_back` to be more consistent with the naming in the stdlib).

Those functions could become free functions thereby leaving `poly_collection` without the dependency on the adaptor template:

```
namespace concept_based_polymorphism {

template <typename DerivedType, typename PtrContainer, typename... Args>
void push(PtrContainer &ptrContainer, Args &&... args) {
  using BaseClass =
      typename std::remove_pointer<typename PtrContainer::value_type>::type;
  std::auto_ptr<BaseClass> owningPointer(
      new DerivedType{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
  ptrContainer.push_back(owningPointer);
}

template <template <typename> class Adapter, typename T, typename PtrContainer>
void push(PtrContainer &ptrContainer, T &&other) {
  using BaseClass =
      typename std::remove_pointer<typename PtrContainer::value_type>::type;
  std::auto_ptr<BaseClass> ptr(new Adapter<T>{std::forward<T>(other)});
  ptrContainer.push_back(ptr);
}
}
```

These functions are designed to work on boost's pointer containers but you could overload them to work with other types of containers as well. The `boost::ptr_` work with `std::auto_ptr` so the code is a bit uglier than it could be (one could write a `make_auto_ptr` helper analogous to `make_unique` to make it somewhat prettier).

Using them makes it mandatory to supply the `Adapter` type so you could provide overload/shortcuts per adapter:

```
template<typename DerivedType, typename PtrContainer, typename ... Args>
void push_shape(PtrContainer &ptrContainer, Args&&... args) {
    using concept_based_polymorphism::push;
    push<ShapeAdapter<DerivedType>>(ptrContainer, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename T, typename PtrContainer>
void push_shape(PtrContainer &ptrContainer, T&& other) {
    using concept_based_polymorphism::push;
    push<ShapeAdapter>(ptrContainer, other);
}
```

Given these shortcuts we can now do this:

```
int main()
{

    boost::ptr_vector<Shape> shapes;

    push_shape<Circle>(shapes, 1, 2, 3);
    push_shape<Rectangle>(shapes, 4, 5, 6, 7);

    Circle c = { 8, 9, 10 };
    push_shape(shapes, c);

    for (auto&& shape: shapes)
    {
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

Which works like the code before. But with the added bonus that you can now easily switch the container and don't have to duplicate its interface.

If you want to retain the nicer push interface where the adaptor type is stored in the container, I would recommend a shallow wrapper that leaves the base container accessible and parametrizable, thus allowing for the "easier" `push` functions to be combined with the reduced code duplication of not having to forward the wrapped containers interface:

```
template <typename ContainerType, template <typename> class Adapter>
struct poly_container_adaptor {
    ContainerType container;
};
```

Now the pushes would work with `poly_container_adaptor` and "normal" code would just get passed the container.

Comment: The problem with the `push_shape` solution is that it forces to create a `push_*` method per adapter (the generic solution is to rewrite `ShapeAdapter` everytime we call `push_shape`, which isn't pretty) and uses a free function for what is usually a class method. I intended at some point to have a template parameter to switch containers as you propose, but since I didn't need that, I ended up not implementing it.

Comment: Your points about missing subtypes and functions names are good though. That said, I don't think that there could be any sane `value_type` here.

Comment: The `boost::ptr_*` containers define `typedef pointer value_type` maybe you could use that as an orientation what to do. The `poly_container_adaptor` would allow for a generic push member (without giving the adaptor). There is a problem with passing the adaptor as template template parameter: You can only use templates that fit this pattern. The `push_*` are more generic in that regard. Whether the functions should be members or not is more of a style preference. Both members and nonmembers can (&) and cannot (const &) change parameters.

Comment: `boost::ptr_*` define `value_type` because it is clear from their design that they store pointers. I wanted a collection of instances derived from an "interface" without exposing the pointers anywhere, hence the lack of meaningful `value_type` (and I am no at ease with `reference != value_type&`). I don't think that the teamplte template is a problem since the collection already requires the user to write an adapter; it is not trying to use any existing class as the adapter.